# Oil specification for my gasoline powered generator

Tags: oil

Does an oil with an API Rating of SN (the most current) meet the standards of all proceeding ratings (SL/SJ in particular). The generator specifies "SL/SJ" but I'm having trouble finding it. Can I use "SN"?

Answer (score 1):

You are fine to use the API SN rated oils. Here is an excerpt from the [API website](http://www.pqiamerica.com/apiserviceclass.htm):

> Introduced in October 2010 for **2011 and older vehicles**, designed to provide improved high temperature deposit protection for pistons, more stringent sludge control, and seal compatibility. API SN with Resource Conserving matches ILSAC GF-5 by combining API SN performance with improved fuel economy, turbocharger protection, emission control system compatibility, and protection of engines operating on ethanol-containing fuels up to E85.